# Calling a remote procedure from a subscriber and resolving the asyncio promise

Tags: python, python-3.x, autobahn, python-asyncio

I'm having problems getting asyncio based autobahn RPCs to work in an event handler:

```
from autobahn.asyncio import wamp
from autobahn.wamp import register, subscribe

class Foo(wamp.ApplicationSession):
    @subscribe('wamp.metaevent.session.on_join')
    def bar(self):
        baz = yield from self.call('baz')

    @register('baz')
    def baz(self):
        return 'baz'
```

Reading the documentation, I'm under the impression that this *should* work. However, if I'm using `yield` inside `Foo.bar` none of its code is being executed at all. I've tried decorating with `asyncio.coroutine` in various patterns, but can't get it to run at all.

The only way I've found to make it work is by resolving the returned future "manually":

```
@subscribe('wamp.metaevent.session.on_join')
def bar(self):
    def do_something(f):
        print(f.result())

    f = self.call('baz')
    f.add_done_callback(do_something)
```

I'm sure I'm just not understanding asyncio programming correctly yet, so what do I have to do to be able to write `baz = self.call('baz')` and get the result immediately (meaning without additional explicitly stated callbacks)?

Comment: Have you tried marking `bar` with `@coroutine`?

Comment: Because `bar` uses `yield from`, it's not a regular function. When you call `bar()`, a _generator object_ is created. The body of `bar` is not executed until you start driving the generator object using `next()`. The `asyncio` event loop should take care of calling `next` for you, but it expects generators to be marked with `@coroutine`. I'm not familiar with the `autobahn` API, so I don't know whether you're using `subscribe` correctly, but my guess is that you're missing an `@coroutine` decorator somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, scratch my previous comment, I got mixed up. Yes, I tried decorating `bar` with `@coroutine`, which didn't help at all.

Comment: Your second version of `bar` does not feature any `yield` statements, so it works as a regular function, and `subscribe` handles it as that. Consult [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) for more information about generators.

Comment: My advice would be to look around the autobahn docs for a version of `subscribe` which expects a coroutine. You could also explicitly register your coroutine with the `asyncio` event loop using `asyncio.async(my_generator_function())`.

Comment: I see, this starts to make sense now. So the question becomes *Can I `subscribe` a generator in Autobahn?*, right?

Comment: Exactly! I don't have time right now but later this morning I'll write up an answer which demonstrates `async`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of [the `yield` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) in the body of a `def` statement makes the defined function into a [*generator function*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator).

When you call a generator function (as `autobahn` would), *the body of the function is not executed*. Instead, a *generator object* is created. When you call `next` on the generator, control advances to the next `yield` statement. Generators have been discussed extensively in other Stack Overflow posts, as well as in the docs and elsewhere on the web.

The API of `asyncio` makes extensive use of [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) and `yield from`. (For most purposes, you can consider 'coroutine' and 'generator' to be synonymous.) The [event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) tracks a collection of generators and calls `next`, `send` and `throw` on them as appropriate.*

It looks like `autobahn.subscribe` expects a regular callback function, not a coroutine, and that's why your code is not getting executed. One way to work around this is to write a callback function that *schedules* your coroutine, using [`asyncio.async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.async).

```
class Foo(wamp.ApplicationSession):
    @subscribe('wamp.metaevent.session.on_join')
    def schedule_bar(self):
        coro = self.bar()  # create the coroutine object

        # wrap the coroutine in a Task and register it with the event loop.
        # the loop argument is optional and defaults to asyncio.get_event_loop()
        asyncio.async(coro, loop=my_event_loop)  

    @coroutine
    def bar(self):
        baz = yield from self.call('baz')

    @register('baz')
    def baz(self):
        return 'baz'
```

In the absence of a function in `autobahn` to do this, you can write your own reusable decorator to subscribe coroutines to WAMP topics.

```
from functools import wraps

def subscribe_coro(uri, loop=None):
    def decorator(f):
        @subscribe(uri)
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            coro = f(*args, **kwargs)
            asyncio.async(coro, loop=loop)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Now your class will look like this:

```
class Foo(wamp.ApplicationSession):
    @subscribe_coro('wamp.metaevent.session.on_join')
    @coroutine
    def bar(self):
        baz = yield from self.call('baz')

    @register('baz')
    def baz(self):
        return 'baz'
```

<sub>* This is a simplification. The event loop in fact tracks [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#future)s, not coroutines. The algorithm to call the appropriate methods on a generator is implemented by [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task), which wraps a coroutine up into a `Future`.</sub>

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test that example code so I may have made a few minor mistakes ;)

Comment: Awesome stuff! I'll play around with this a bit. At least the issue makes a lot of sense to me now.

Comment: @deceze I've updated my post with links to the docs and corrected a few typos

Comment: Works great! Just a minor quibble in the `asyncio.async` call which I corrected above.